# Can you use the variable of an out parameter as the next argument to another function in the same expression as the call which sets the out parameter?

Tags: c#, argument-passing

Is this code safe, and will it do what I expect?  Are there any pitfalls?  Is it necessary that GenerateValue use a ref parameter, or would the method taking that argument by value also work?

```
 int value;
 UseValue(GenerateValue(out value), ref value);
```

Method definition should not affect the answer, but here is an example definition:

```
    private bool GenerateValue(out int value)
    {
        bool success = true;
        value = 42;
        return success;
    }

    private void UseValue(bool success, ref int value)
    {
        if (success)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't need to be `ref` in `UseValue`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is safe. Basically it is equivalent of

```
int value;
bool res = GenerateValue(out value);
UseValue(res, ref value);
```

Please note, as **@sstan** commented, that `ref` is not really needed in our case. But even if it would be needed due to change of `value` inside `Usevalue`, the code still stays OK.

Answer (score 1):

`UseValue(GenerateValue(out value), value);`

it's also fine. think it sequential call.